# Why font is changed automatically in LibreOffice for Linux?

Tags: linux, fonts, linux-mint, libreoffice

I'm using LibreOffice 6.1 on Linux Mint 17. I would like to create a presentation using **Impress**. I set the font to **Droid Arabic Naskh**. Then, I save and close the file. When I open it again, the font is changed automatically to **DejaVu Sans**. Is it a bug or something? How can I solve it? I'm writing in **Arabic** language.